# IntelliJ method to register usage of features

Tags: intellij-idea

once I saw that IntelliJ IDEA had a class to register the usage of the IDE features, I suppose for analysing the most used features, but I can't find it right now, does someone know the name of this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is called FeatureUsageTracker.
And the best place to ask IntelliJ IDEA plugin development questions is the forum at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development